# Get json dynamic key in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I need to get the key & value from a JSON to add it in an option created in JS.

In my html, I've just add input hidden to get data in JS like this :

```html
<input type="hidden" value="<?= htmlspecialchars(json_encode($availableFlag)) ?>" id="list-flag">
```

`$availableFlag` is defined in my php just above :

```php
$availableFlag = App::getAvailableTags();
```

And this function is defined in another class and give me that :

```php
public static function getAvailableTags(): array {
        return array_merge(self::$availableTags, [
            Tag::TAG_OUT_UE => Tag::TAG_TYPE_ERROR, // Those variables are const
            Tag::TAG_PHYSICAL_TICKET     => Tag::TAG_TYPE_WARNING, // defined in the Tag class
        ]);
    }
```

So, back to my main problem. I'm creating dynamic options based on the lenght of my array

```js
const listFlag = JSON.parse(oid("list-flag").value);
        
for (let i = 0; i < listFlag.length; i++) {
    filterFlagSelect.options[filterFlagSelect.options.length] = new Option(listFlag[i], listFlag[i]);
}
```

But `listFlag[i]` is undefined, and I don't know what to do because keys in `listFlag` is never the same.

This is my content in `listFlag`

```json
{
  "out-ue": "error",
  "physical-ticket": "warning"
}
```

And listFlag.length seem to have problems too

Comment: `listFlag` is an object and not an array -> [Working with objects - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects)

Comment: Why do you create them on the client (after a workaround to get the data to the client) and not directly on the server?

Comment: @Andreas Yes, I've just notice that. So I've found `Object.keys(listFlag)[i]` can be usefull

You mean the options or the tags ?